# Compare data in Accumulo vs Solr?

Tags: solr, accumulo

I am trying to compare data ingested into both Accumulo and Solr from the same source XML. The data ingested into Accumulo is legacy code while Solr is new code. I can easily extract out data from Solr using SolrCloud and choosing CSV or JSON, which is easily readable. But I'm at a loss for how to easily view the data in Accumulo. I used scan to view the data, but it is not easily readable. Is there a way to export the data in Accumulo to a CSV or something similar so it will be easy to read/compare with other datasets?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a document store which uses Lucene indexes to make search fast via a web-based REST interface. On the other hand, [Apache Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/) is a massively scalable sorted key-value store, which stores arbitrary key-value pairs with cell-level security labels, in accordance with the user's application, queryable with a Java API. It makes no sense to compare the two. They are entirely different applications. Accumulo is a low-level infrastructure application, upon which you can build complex systems, such as a search engine comparable to Solr, but it is not directly comparable to Solr because Accumulo is not a search engine.

To answer your question about how to view data in Accumulo, the answer is to use its Java API. I recommend starting with the [Tour](https://accumulo.apache.org/tour/) on its web page, for some examples of how to query it. As for how the data is presented, and in what form, that depends on the application which ingested it in the first place. It can be arbitrary binary data in byte arrays and may not be directly viewable; that depends on the application. Accumulo is agnostic to the nature of the data stored in its key-value pairs.

What you were probably referring to in your question, when you said *"I used scan to view the data"*, you were probably referring to the `scan` command in Accumulo's shell. You should probably be aware that the shell is not the primary interface for query. It is intended for system administration and triage of data ingest. The Java API is the primary means of querying.

The Accumulo open source community is pretty responsive to questions. If you're having trouble figuring out how best to use it for your needs, I would advise to ask on their community mailing lists, which can be found at their website. StackOverflow is more suitable for very specific questions than generalized "getting started" kinds of tutorials.